# How search filter in pingfederate PCV works

Tags: pingfederate

I am struggling to understand pingfederate LDAP Password credential validator's search filter.

If my sso is going to have HTML form adapter and user enters username/password how this search filter authenticates exactly?

Is PCV pulling the record or transferring the credentials entered by user to LDAP datastore for authentication?

Comment: Please add a code snippet to and/or error message and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a filter like:

```
sAMAccountName=${username}
```

then all that does is tell PingFederate how to search for the user. It then does an authenticated bind as that filtered user to the LDAP data store, retrieving any additional attributes as needed according to the adapter contract.

Answer (score 0):

The example filter from Andrew works for a single attribute in the LDAP data store.  The specific example is for the Active Directory field sAMAccountName that would contain the NT username.  The LDAP filter can also be more complex.  We have found that there are use cases for searching for the user either by the NT Login username or by email address. The syntax would be as follows:

```
(|(sAMAccountName=${username})(mail=${username}))
```